# A phrase similar to murmurs of laughter

Tags: word-choice, phrasing

I am writing an essay and one thing I am talking about is that I hear small laughs among the crowd while I nervously give a speech. I used the phrase "murmurs of laughter" but a peer said that it did not make sense, and it seems like I might have mixed it up with a different phrase. Does anyone know a concise way to word this that is possibly similar to "murmurs of laughter"

Comment: Hi Alan, welcome to writing.se! Take the [tour] and visit the [help] for more information. Unfortunately requests for specific phrases are off-topic on our site. But you can ask them over on [English.se] but be sure to review their posting guidelines before asking. Good luck and happy writing!

Answer (score 0):

***Murmured low Appreciation [it's a kinda funny question...]  :)***

"Murmured laughter" is the same as what you said, but less awkward. Laughter is okay by itself, but to make it smaller, small laughs are giggles or chuckles, or perhaps a snort. To make it even smaller, describe them as "low" or "tiny," so "low laughter" is more than a chuckle, "tiny giggles" are barely heard. Even smaller still would be "appreciative noises" which isn't even laughing, really, but shows someone understands and appreciates a joke.

You can also try other synonyms for laughter, and see what sound right to you.